# Undefined touch using ngDraggable (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing an application with AngularJS and a component called ngDraggable, but i'm having some trouble with touch events. When a touch event for drag is executed an error is shown on console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined    ngDraggable.js:118
onlongpress   ngDraggable.js:118
(anonymous function) ngDraggable.js:95
```

I've already tried to debug the code, and the variable `evt` does not have the array `touches` as it have on the examples codes.

Does anybody have an idea how can I solve this problem?

Below a snippet where the code have problem:

```
var onlongpress = function(evt) {
   if(! _dragEnabled)return;
   evt.preventDefault();
   element.addClass('dragging');
   offset = _privoffset(element); 
   element.centerX = element[0].offsetWidth / 2;
   element.centerY = element[0].offsetHeight / 2;    
   _mx = (evt.pageX || evt.touches[0].pageX);        // <---- This is the line the problem occurs
   _my = (evt.pageY || evt.touches[0].pageY);
   _mrx = _mx - offset.left;
   _mry = _my - offset.top;
   if (_centerAnchor) {
       _tx = _mx - element.centerX - $window.pageXOffset;
       _ty = _my - element.centerY - $window.pageYOffset;
   } else {
       _tx = _mx - _mrx - $window.pageXOffset;
       _ty = _my - _mry - $window.pageYOffset;
   }
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem.

They just updated the module. Just update the module with the last release and the problem is solved.